# How to login identity core user without reloading page in Blazor server?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I discovered several issues and problems about Blazor server side and problematic authentication.

The only easiest solution right now is to force-simulate cookie based authentication by reloading page to route which will fill browser with cookies and save session in server, then redirect back to Blazor hub, where all SignalR requests will now be filled with authentication.

All other solutions are hard as hell to implement (using JS Interop to fill SignalR with token or something).

My website was based on cool-react-angular-like behaviour of Blazor components, so making users to experience page reload for authentication, when everything else is so quick and fluid - kinda not an option. Not to mention that almost all components in website listening for AuthenticationStateProvider event to change if user is is authenticated.

Unfortunately, I stumbled upon authentication problem after all of website components were already done and styled.

Maybe now, after half of a year of Blazor server authentication issues, somebody knows how to implement it easily and without writing numerous files to create bridge between Identity Core and Blazor server side?

Comment: I think the best you will get is how Blazor Oqtane does it. We open up a "login popup window" https://github.com/oqtane/oqtane.framework/